# Someone downvoted four of my answers in a short time

Tags: discussion

I am not sure if this is just a coincidence, nor that it is appropriate on this site. What do you think?

The answers are as follows:[one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable/11589#11589), [two](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12580/easily-show-rows-that-are-different-between-two-tables-or-queries/12587#12587), [three](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10655/is-nolock-always-bad/10669#10669), and [four](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/629/passing-array-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure/12389#12389).

Comment: Happens [all the time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28756/169197) on SO, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of those answers have downvotes on them now so perhaps the system picked up the suspicious voting pattern and rolled them back?

You are right, behaviour like that is completely inappropriate. Even mods cannot find out *who* placed a vote (short of looking at every user's rep history) but if anything like this happens again let us know and we'll try and get the user suspended through the network.

Comment: Thank you Jack!